# Update from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.2.x RabbitMQ doesn't declare bindings with a list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I used to declare queues, exchanges and bindings in one of my configuration files as follows:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class MyRabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange firstExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("firstExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue firstQueue() {
        return new Queue("firstQueue", true, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange secondExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("secondExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue secondQueue() {
        return new Queue("secondQueue", true, true, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public List<Declarable> bindings() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                BindingBuilder.bind(firstQueue()).to(firstExchange()),
                BindingBuilder.bind(secondQueue()).to(secondExchange()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

And this used to work pretty well. After updating from Spring Boot 1.5.x (obviously the starters as well) to Spring Boot 2.2.x, everything still work, except for `Binding`s. When I replace:

```
@Bean
public List<Declarable> bindings() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            BindingBuilder.bind(firstQueue()).to(firstExchange()),
            BindingBuilder.bind(secondQueue()).to(secondExchange()));
}
```

with:

```
@Bean
public Binding firstBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(firstQueue()).to(firstExchange());
}

@Bean
public Binding secondBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(secondQueue()).to(secondExchange());
}
```

it starts to work as I expect and I still have my `Binding`s. I suspect it has something to do with [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#conditional-declaration), but couldn't figure out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Declarables` instead.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#collection-declaration

Pay attention to the IMPORTANT block:

> In versions prior to 2.1, you could declare multiple `Declarable` instances by defining beans of type `Collection<Declarable>`. This can cause undesirable side effects in some cases, because the admin has to iterate over all `Collection<?>` beans. This feature is now disabled in favor of `Declarables`, as discussed earlier in this section. You can revert to the previous behavior by setting the `RabbitAdmin` property called `declareCollections` to `true`.